# MVC Action Filters using parameters passed to the for ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I created a custom [Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) with no problem.

But I would like to modify the Action Filter to use some of the parameters actually passed to my method.

So if I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
[MyAttribute]
public ActionResult ViewUserDetails(Guid userId)
{
     // Do something
}
```

How can I get access to userId from within `MyAttribute`? Is there a way I can directly pass it in?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to access the USER Id being passed into that parameter. There is probably a way to access the USER id of the user logged in to your system though. And you may be able to access anything in the View data ... but I wouldn't recommend going that route even if you could.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try `OnActionExecuting` override, where you do have access to action parameters.

```
public class MyAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {    
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("userId"))
        {
            var userId = filterContext.ActionParameters["userId"] as Guid;
            if (userId != null)
            {
                // Really?! Great!            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute which derives from `FilterAttribute` and implements `IAuthorizationFilter`.

You should also be able to get the user information in the `OnAuthorization` method by accessing `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity` without the need to pass the userid.

Comment: I don't think he's necessarily looking for the logged in users id, it looks more like he's making an admin page to view any user.