# Access action method parameters from custom Authorize attribute in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authorize-attribute

I am writing an MVC 3 app where users will be able to log in and manage their data.  I want to prevent users from viewing or tampering with other user's data.  My first instinct was to just verify access to the relevant object in each action method like this:

```
public ActionResult ShowDetails(int objectId)
{
    DetailObject detail = _repo.GetById(objectId);
    if (detail.User.UserID != (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LogOff", "Account");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I thought it might be better to put the object authorization code into a custom Authorize attribute derived from AuthorizeAttribute, which I could then apply to the controller.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way to access the action method parameters from within my custom Authorize attribute.  Instead, the only way I have found to access the incoming objectId is by examining httpContext.Request or filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private int _objectId = 0;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _unitOfWork = uow;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        int.TryParse((string) filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"], out _objectId);
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        int objectId = 0;
        if (httpContext.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("id", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            int.TryParse(httpContext.Request[idKey], out objectId);
        }

        if (objectId != 0)
        {
            if (!IsAuthorized(objectId, httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (_objectId != 0)
        {
            if (!IsAuthorized(objectId, httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    private bool IsAuthorized(int objectId, string userName)
    {
        DetailObject detail;
        detail = _unitOfWork.ObjectRepository.GetById(objectId);

        if (detail == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (userName != detail.User.UserName)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I find this approach to be very clunky.  I really don't want to have to poke around in the RouteData or Request objects; it would be much cleaner to be able to access the action method parameters since model binding would have already pulled out the relevant data from the RouteData and Request.

I know I can access action method parameters from a custom Action Filter (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203329/mvc-action-filters-using-parameters-passed-to-the-for-actionresult?answertab=votes#tab-top)), but shouldn't data authorization code be placed in an Authorize Filter?  The more examples I see of Authorize filters, the more I get the impression that they are intended only to handle roles.

My main question is: How do I access action method parameters from my custom Authorize Attribute?

Comment: You found any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your main question: no, unfortunately `AuthorizationContext` does not provide access to action parameters.

First off, you could use `ValueProvider` to not have to deal with whether the id is part of the route or a query parameter or HTTP posted, as follows:

```cs
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    string id = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("id").AttemptedValue;
    ...
}
```

This works for simple data types and introduces little overhead. However once you start using custom model binders for your action parameters, you have to inherit your filter from `ActionFilterAttribute` to avoid double binding:

```cs
[MyFilter]
public ActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))] MyModel model)
{
    ...
}

public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] as MyModel;
        ...
    }
}
```

While semantically inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` for authorization purposes sounds better, there are no other reasons for doing this. Moreover, I find using `ActionFilterAttribute` easier, as all you have to do is override only one method, not keeping a state for subsequent methods.